# Show that the partial sums $S_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{10^{k!}}$ form a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'd like to determine whether $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{10^{n!}}$ is convergent. To this end, I have to consider its partial sums $S_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{10^{k!}}$ and show that these partial sums form a convergent sequence. By virtue of $\mathbb{R}$, I decide to show that these $S_n$'s actually constitute a Cauchy sequence. Suppose $m>n$. Then
$$|S_m-S_n|=\frac{1}{10^{m!}}+\frac{1}{10^{(m-1)!}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{10^{(n+1)!}}.$$
Now I don't know what to do next, because of those disturbing factorials. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Comment: It would be easier to use $\frac{1}{10^{n!}} \le \frac{1}{10^n}$ and a comparison theorem :)

Comment: Every convergent sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: @MartinR Good for you, Martin! You are the best!

Answer (score 1):

Let me use $n!+k\le(n+k)!$ for sufficiently large n. then...

$$|S_m-S_n|=\frac{1}{10^{m!}}+\frac{1}{10^{(m-1)!}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{10^{(n+1)!}}=\sum_{i=1}^{m-n}10^{(n+i)!}\le\sum_{i=1}^{m-n}10^{n!+i}<\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}10^{n!+i}=\frac1{9\cdot10^{n!}}$$

Comment: Thank you, but how did you get the last equality?